# How can one extract values from RenderConfig in Haskell's SDL bindings

Tags: haskell, haskell-sdl

This is probably a beginner mistake, as it is my first "real" attempt at using Haskell.

My relevant code snippets look like:

```
import           SDL            (RendererConfig, RendererType(SoftwareRenderer), defaultRenderer)

defaultRendererType :: RendererType
defaultRendererType = case defaultRenderer of
  RendererConfig rt  _ -> rt
```

Notably, ghc doesn't complain about the import of `RendererConfig`, which makes me thing I'm using it wrong.

The source of `RendererConfig` looks like it only has two arguments, so I'm not sure why the match isn't working in the case expression.

```
data RendererConfig = RendererConfig
  { rendererType  :: RendererType
    -- ^ The renderer's acceleration mode
  , rendererTargetTexture :: Bool
    -- ^ The renderer supports rendering to texture
} deriving (Data, Eq, Generic, Ord, Read, Show, Typeable)
```

**Edit**

The error message I get:

```
Main.hs:47:3: error:                                                                                   
    Not in scope: data constructor `RendererConfig'                                                                                     
    Perhaps you want to add `RendererConfig' to the import list                                                                         
    in the import of `SDL' (app/Main.hs:10:1-97).                                                                                       
   |                                                                                                                                    
47 |   RendererConfig rt  _ -> rt                                                                                                       
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: What's the error say? I'd rather not try to get SDL installed to check, but I bet you just want to change your import to `RendererConfig(RendererConfig)` or `RendererConfig(..)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner right, thanks! updated

Answer (score 0):

It was pointed out to me that `RendererConfig` [has no constructors exported](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sdl2-2.4.1.0/docs/SDL-Video-Renderer.html#t:RendererType). However, since it does derive `Show`, I can, after the proper import, still get what I want, and much more simply: `rendererType(defaultRenderer)`.

Comment: Your link shows four exported constructors, which contradicts your claim that no constructors are exported. It's also for `RendererType`, not `RendererConfig`. Both types export all their constructors. The problem is your *import* list, not the exports: `import Foo (Bar)` imports the type constructor `Bar`, but does not import any of the data constructors for `Bar`. You need `import Foo (Bar(Baz))` to import data constructor `Baz` of type constructor `Bar` or `import Foo (Bar(..))` to import all data constructors for type constructor `Bar`.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, but your comment makes sense. Thanks!